# What is the difference between react-stripe-checkout and react-stripe-js?

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

I am trying to implement an e-commerce payment functionality with stripe. I found two packages that seems to offer the payment functionality

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-stripe-checkout
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/@stripe/react-stripe-js

What is the difference? Under what situation should I use one vs the other?

Comment: You have duplicated links. Second probably should be https://www.npmjs.com/package/@stripe/react-stripe-js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 **@stripe/react-stripe-js** - is an official Stripe package. It uses [Stripe.js and Elements](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js) so you could build payment form on your website.
2 **react-stripe-checkout** - is not official. It uses [Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout) flow with Stripe-hosted payment page.

Answer (score 2):

`react-stripe-checkout` is a 3rd party React wrapper for the Stripe Legacy Checkout product. It's not recommended you use this as Legacy Checkout has been deprecated. Also the library hasn't been updated in 3 years.

`react-stripe-js` is the official Stripe React library for Stripe Elements. You should use this as it is up to date with the Stripe ecosystem and is compatible with modern React concepts like hooks.