# React stripe checkout does not allow me to proceed the payment

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, stripe-payments

I am struck with this error "Uncaught Error: You did not set a valid publishable key. Call Stripe.setPublishableKey() with your publishable key. For more info, see [https://stripe.com/docs/stripe.js"](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe.js%22) on React. I can't find the reason behind this error. I have saved my public key on .env file as REACT_APP_STRIPE. Here is my React Page code,

```
     import { Add, Remove } from "@material-ui/icons";
     import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
     import styled from "styled-components";
     import Announcement from "../components/Announcement";
     import Footer from "../components/Footer";
     import Navbar from "../components/Navbar";
    import { mobile } from "../responsive";
    import StripeCheckout from "react-stripe-checkout";
    import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
     import { userRequest } from "../requestMethod";
     import { useHistory } from "react-router";

    const KEY = process.env.REACT_APP_STRIPE;

    const Container = styled.div``;

const Wrapper = styled.div`
  padding: 20px;
  ${mobile({ padding: "10px" })}
`;

const Title = styled.h1`
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: center;
`;

const Top = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 20px;
`;

const TopButton = styled.button`
  padding: 10px;
  font-weight: 600;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: ${(props) => props.type === "filled" && "none"};
  background-color: ${(props) =>
    props.type === "filled" ? "black" : "transparent"};
  color: ${(props) => props.type === "filled" && "white"};
`;

const TopTexts = styled.div`
  ${mobile({ display: "none" })}
`;
const TopText = styled.span`
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0px 10px;
`;

const Bottom = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  ${mobile({ flexDirection: "column" })}
`;

const Info = styled.div`
  flex: 3;
`;

const Product = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  ${mobile({ flexDirection: "column" })}
`;

const ProductDetail = styled.div`
  flex: 2;
  display: flex;
`;

const Image = styled.img`
  width: 200px;
`;

const Details = styled.div`
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
`;

const ProductName = styled.span``;

const ProductId = styled.span``;

const ProductColor = styled.div`
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: ${(props) => props.color};
`;

const ProductSize = styled.span``;

const PriceDetail = styled.div`
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
`;

const ProductAmountContainer = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
`;

const ProductAmount = styled.div`
  font-size: 24px;
  margin: 5px;
  ${mobile({ margin: "5px 15px" })}
`;

const ProductPrice = styled.div`
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 200;
  ${mobile({ marginBottom: "20px" })}
`;

const Hr = styled.hr`
  background-color: #eee;
  border: none;
  height: 1px;
`;

const Summary = styled.div`
  flex: 1;
  border: 0.5px solid lightgray;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  height: 50vh;
`;

const SummaryTitle = styled.h1`
  font-weight: 200;
`;

const SummaryItem = styled.div`
  margin: 30px 0px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  font-weight: ${(props) => props.type === "total" && "500"};
  font-size: ${(props) => props.type === "total" && "24px"};
`;

const SummaryItemText = styled.span``;

const SummaryItemPrice = styled.span``;

const Button = styled.button`
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 600;
`;

const Cart = () => {
  const cart = useSelector((state) => state.cart);
  const [stripeToken, setStripeToken] = useState(null);
  const history = useHistory();

  const onToken = (token) => {
    setStripeToken(token);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const makeRequest = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await userRequest.post("/checkout/payment", {
          tokenId: stripeToken.id,
          amount: 500,
        });
        history.push("/success", {
          stripeData: res.data,
          products: cart,
        });
      } catch {}
    };
    stripeToken && makeRequest();
  }, [stripeToken, cart.total, history]);
  return (
    <Container>
      <Navbar />
      <Announcement />
      <Wrapper>
        <Title>YOUR BAG</Title>
        <Top>
          <TopButton>CONTINUE SHOPPING</TopButton>
          <TopTexts>
            <TopText>Shopping Bag(2)</TopText>
            <TopText>Your Wishlist (0)</TopText>
          </TopTexts>
          <TopButton type="filled">CHECKOUT NOW</TopButton>
        </Top>
        <Bottom>
          <Info>
            {cart.product.map((product) => (
              <Product>
                <ProductDetail>
                  <Image src={product.img} />
                  <Details>
                    <ProductName>
                      <b>Product:</b> {product.title}
                    </ProductName>
                    <ProductId>
                      <b>ID:</b> {product._id}
                    </ProductId>
                    <ProductColor color={product.color} />
                    <ProductSize>
                      <b>Size:</b> {product.size}
                    </ProductSize>
                  </Details>
                </ProductDetail>
                <PriceDetail>
                  <ProductAmountContainer>
                    <Add />
                    <ProductAmount>{product.quantity}</ProductAmount>
                    <Remove />
                  </ProductAmountContainer>
                  <ProductPrice>
                    $ {product.price * product.quantity}
                  </ProductPrice>
                </PriceDetail>
              </Product>
            ))}
            <Hr />
          </Info>
          <Summary>
            <SummaryTitle>ORDER SUMMARY</SummaryTitle>
            <SummaryItem>
              <SummaryItemText>Subtotal</SummaryItemText>
              <SummaryItemPrice>$ {cart.total}</SummaryItemPrice>
            </SummaryItem>
            <SummaryItem>
              <SummaryItemText>Estimated Shipping</SummaryItemText>
              <SummaryItemPrice>$ 5.90</SummaryItemPrice>
            </SummaryItem>
            <SummaryItem>
              <SummaryItemText>Shipping Discount</SummaryItemText>
              <SummaryItemPrice>$ -5.90</SummaryItemPrice>
            </SummaryItem>
            <SummaryItem type="total">
              <SummaryItemText>Total</SummaryItemText>
              <SummaryItemPrice>$ {cart.total}</SummaryItemPrice>
            </SummaryItem>
            <StripeCheckout
              name="Ecommerce"
              image="https://c7.alamy.com/comp/2C42TCR/man-avatar-with-smartphone-bank-and-coins-of-online-payments-money-and-ecommerce-theme-vector-illustration-2C42TCR.jpg"
              billingAddress
              shippingAddress
              description={`Your total is $${cart.total}`}
              amount={cart.total * 100}
              token={onToken}
              stripeKey={KEY}
            >
              <Button>CHECKOUT NOW</Button>
            </StripeCheckout>
          </Summary>
        </Bottom>
      </Wrapper>
      <Footer />
    </Container>
  );
};

export default Cart;
```

This is my request method,

```
import axios from "axios";

const BASE_URL = "http://localhost:8080/api/";
const TOKEN =
  "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjYxZmQ2YTRjZTQ4OGE1NzEzYTVhMWQwNyIsImlzQWRtaW4iOnRydWUsImlhdCI6MTY0NDI1ODU0NSwiZXhwIjoxNjQ0NTE3NzQ1fQ.bZqm0zISuMf_4XdVoZqxPAATecY_-k6-kSpFGPgh4cU";

export const publicRequest = axios.create({
  baseURL: BASE_URL,
});

export const userRequest = axios.create({
  baseURL: BASE_URL,
  headers: { token: `Bearer ${TOKEN}` },
});
```

This is my redux slice,

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const cartSlice = createSlice({
  name: "cart",
  initialState: {
    product: [],
    quantity: 0,
    total: 0,
  },
  reducers: {
    addProduct: (state, action) => {
      state.quantity += 1; //cart quantity
      state.product.push(action.payload);
      state.total += action.payload.price * action.payload.quantity; //product quantity
    },
  },
});

export const { addProduct } = cartSlice.actions;
export default cartSlice.reducer;
```

Can someone help?

Comment: Log the value of `process.env.REACT_APP_STRIPE` and make sure it's correctly set.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, use original source (**@stripe/react-stripe-js**)  not 3rd part (**react-stripe-checkout**) .Look at (https://stackoverflow.com/a/64997958/10751265 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/64997936/10751265)

Secondly for your situation, you used

```
const KEY = process.env.REACT_APP_STRIPE;
```

but your key should be string, like

```
const KEY = "your key here"
```